# Basic angular 2 authentication

Tags: angular

I am calling a simple get request through localhost.I don't know what wrong with the code.I checked it so many time.It didn't find any error.Someone check my code tell what I am missing.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    //private _productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';
    //private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:8092/openmrs-standalone/ws/rest/v1/concept';
    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:8092/openmrs-standalone/ws/rest/v1/session';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<any> {

         let username: string = 'admin';
         let password: string = 'Admin123';
         let headers: Headers = new Headers();
         headers.append("authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
         headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
         let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

         return this._http.get(this._productUrl,options)

            .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
     private handleError(error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does function getProducts() call auth API ?

Comment: I am doing just it for testing purpose.I want to call the rest api to get the data back.Newbie to angular 2

Comment: I posted the complete code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:8092/openmrs-standalone/ws/rest/v1/session';

getProducts(): Observable<any> {
   let username: string = 'admin';
   let password: string = 'Admin123';
   let headerOptions = {
      'Accept': `application/json`,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)
   };
   let headers = new Headers(headerOptions );
   return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
}
```

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8092/openmrs-standalone/ws/rest/v1/session. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: I think this error come from server, you should add config Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to allow CORS

Comment: how do I add this code.kindly give me example.thanks

Comment: You should update question with BE info or make new question with different tag. I'm not sure about your server

Comment: my server is online.I am using openmrs to get fetch the record.I don't have access to the server side code.password  and user name for server are:Admin123 and admin.I am writing rest api to connect with server to fetch the record.

Comment: Here is a link to openmrs.It's a online demo openmrs which provide rest api access.I am trying to get data from this server.https://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/module/webservices/rest/test.htm